# How do I reload the terminal in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

How can I restart / reload the terminal in ubuntu 11.10? I'm using bash. My original reason to ask was that I had to exit and start the terminal again to get new .bashrc aliases to work, but that's fixed by reloading it with ".", now I'm just curious.

Comment: What do you mean? What exactly do you want to re-load?

Comment: Basically I'd want the same effect as closing and then starting bash again. If possible with the text in the window still intact, but that's probably much more complicated and I'd settle for losing it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Run

```
bash --login
```

This will start a new bash login shell new loading your profile. It will inherit the other shells environment though, unless some values are overridden.

If you exit this bash, you'll be in your original shell again.

Comment: I guess you could use `exec` to start the new bash shell in the same process?

Comment: `exec bash` seems to work, as does `bash --login; exit`. Alright, solved I guess.

Answer (score 5):

You can load another shell in the terminal. Type:

```
bash
```

You can put some echo commentary in `.bashrc` to verify. To verify all aliases type:

```
alias
```